# end to end Karate tests fail because GitHub cannot talk to DB in AWS

Tags: database, continuous-integration, github-actions, karate, testcontainers

I have end to end Karate test cases that involve posting messages via API and validating it in the SQL Server in AWS. I created yaml file in my project. Workflow in GitHub gets triggered whenever there is a push to main branch. Only karate tests that don't involve DB validations pass, but any test that involves DB validation, it fails saying unable to obtain JDBC connection. The same tests when I run them in my local machine with VPN connected, work great.  Here is my yaml file:-

```
name: Karate Test Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Cache Gradle packages
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x karatetest/gradlew

      - name: Build and run Karate tests
        working-directory: ./karate-test-cases
        env:
          KARATE_OPTIONS: ${{ vars.KARATE_OPTIONS }}
          KARATE_ENV: ${{ vars.ENV }}
          TEST_API_URL: ${{ secrets.APIURL }}
          TEST_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DB_USERNAME }}
          TEST_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
          TEST_URL: ${{ secrets.SERVER_URL }}
          TEST_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: ${{ secrets.DRIVERCLASSNAME }}

        run: |
          ./gradlew test \
            -Dkarate.options="$KARATE_OPTIONS" \
            -Dkarate.env="$KARATE_ENV" \
            -Dtest.apiurl="$TEST_API_URL" \
            -Dtest.username="$TEST_USERNAME" \
            -Dtest.password="$TEST_PASSWORD" \
            -Dtest.url="$TEST_URL" \
            -Dtest.driverClassName="$TEST_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME" \

      - name: Upload Karate Test Report
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          name: karatereports
          retention-days: 1
          path: |
           ./karate-test-cases/build/cucumber-html-reports/
           ./karate-test-cases/build/karate-reports
```

Comment: clearly because connections on the port JDBC uses are not allowed, you have to work with your network / ops folks for this one, no one else can help you:

Comment: As you said in your description, you need to connect to DBMS via a VPN. You need exact same setup in your GHA workflow too. See if you can install and configure your VPN client via command line in your workflow and then run those tests. That should work.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was recommended to use TestContainers as an alternative solution. 1. Create a docker image of the database and stored it in the AWS ECR
2. the test.yaml configures docker in the action to be able to connect to that ECR. I have no experience in this. Any insights would help. I cannot use the VPN client because of security reasons